# Can event bus be used to communicate between different projects or applications

Tags: gwt, event-bus

I am creating a gwt widget library for our internal use. I am asked to fire an event whenever any event occurs on any of the controls in my gwt widget which would then be listened to by the application or project that is using my widget. The concept seemed similar to the event bus that i previously used for my other gwt projects to communicate between different views displayed in different regions on the same page. That worked fine as i was using the same instance of event bus through out the application. But now I would be using a particular instance of the event bus in my project but the application consuming it will not be using the same instance. Do I go ahead and use it or is there an alternate way to fire events between different applications. Please help

Answer (score 3):

First, what do you call "different applications" ? Will they be running in the same browser ? Will they be deployed on the same server ?

You can't use `EventBus` to communicate between your applications if they don't share a common `EventBus`.

If your applications are running in the same tab, you can store the `EventBus` in a static variable, and retrieve it from the other applications in the same tab.

If your applications are running in the same browser (on different tabs), you can use `LocalStorage` to communicate. You can have a look at :

- [Inter-tab communication using local storage](http://blog.fastmail.fm/2012/11/26/inter-tab-communication-using-local-storage/)
- [Using HTML5 Web Storage for Interprocess Communication](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/03/10/using-html5-web-storage-for-interprocess-communication.aspx)
- [Sharing data across windows using localStorage](http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/sharing-messages-and-data-across-windows-using-localstorage/).

GWT provides an implementation of `LocalStorage` (and `SessionStorage`) in `com.google.gwt.storage.client.Storage`.

If they aren't running in the same browser, you will have to do a round-trip to the server to communicate from one application to an other (using RPC to send the message, and RPC polling to check for new messages - or using server push techniques, see [GWTEventService](http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/) and [ServerPushFAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ)).

If they aren't deployed on the same server, you will have to do a round-trip to the server and to communicate between your servers (using sockets, RPC, webservices,...).

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ to the rescue... it's the canonical solution for this type of problem.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/

It was created as a bus for software, much like a hardware bus is to a computer system.

I especially like the http://manning.com/videla/ book. It goes into detail about the approach, outlines source code and the architecture behind it. Very practical.

Comment: Unfortunately, RabbitMQ doesn't work in GWT (GWT code is in fact compiled in JS and run on the browser, so only a subset of Java classes and functionalities are available).